# How can I execute a cmd command through windows run prompt box? (win+R)

Tags: windows, cmd

How can I start a program that I usually run from terminal, right from run prompt? (*win key + R*)

**Example:**

Instead of pressing:

```
win + R, type "cmd", press enter, type "jupyter notebook", press enter
```

I would like to

```
win + R, type "cmd; jupyter notebook", press enter
```

Maybe something like:

```
cmd, jupyter notebook
cmd: jupiter notebook
cmd; jupyter notebook
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you just create a batch file (a file ending in .bat or .cmd) with that line in it and just dbl click that or assign it a shortcut key

Comment: I know how to do that. I'm just curious about Windows features! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type:

```
cmd /c "jupyter notebook"
```

This will close the command prompt after the command has been executed. If you don't want to close the command prompt use /k instead of /c.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Where can I find more about these cmd "/flags"? Btw, how are them called?

Comment: You can find the syntax of how to use the call parameters of `cmd` if you type `help cmd` in the command prompt.

Comment: Almost.. I tried `cmd help`.

Comment: `cmd /?` also works